# How to select unique sessions per unique dates with SQL?

Tags: sql, session, unique, distinct

I'm struggling with my SQL. I want to select all unique sessions on unique dates from a table. I don't get the results I want.

Example of table:

```
session_id | date
87654321   | 2020-05-22 09:10:10
12345678   | 2020-05-23 10:19:50
12345678   | 2020-05-23 10:20:23
87654321   | 2020-05-23 12:00:10
```

This is my SQL right now. I select all distinct dates from a datetime column. I also count all distinct session_id's. I group them by date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'date', COUNT(DISTINCT `session_id`) as 'count' FROM `logging` GROUP BY 'date'
```

What I want to see is (with example above):

```
date       | count
22-05-2020 | 1
23-05-2020 | 2
```

The result I get with my real table (with 354 sessions on 3 different dates) right now is:

```
date       | count
21-05-2020 | 200
```

### Edit

Changes ` to '.

Comment: which SQL engine are you using? please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Just remove DISTINCT from here: `COUNT(DISTINCT session_id)` and you will get a number of all sessions for each date. If you want unique session, then your query is OK.

Comment: Removing DISTINCT from COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) gives the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the field and the name of the alias is the same (`date`). Please try to use different name for the alias to avoid confusion in GROUP BY part

Comment: The confusion with the alias date was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to group on your date expression

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT `session_id`) as `count` FROM `logging` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')
```